# Connect to Azure MQTT using SIM808

Tags: azure, mqtt, ca, sim800

I want to send SIM808 GPS data to the Azure IoT hub using MQTT.
As mentioned in docs of azure, I have used the same parameters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly 
But it doesn't work. Did not published.
Can we connect to Azure MQTT using Username and password without attaching certificate?  if not

**How to create the certificate?**

**How to send SIM808 data to the Azure IoT hub using MQTT?**
Suggest me a way to do it with an example.

**Thanks!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. You can [use tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#security-token-structure).

As a simplest alternative you may also use [flespi telematics hub](https://flespi.com/telematics-hub) to reach same goal. Your device can send via [HTTP](https://flespi.com/protocols/http) or [MQTT](https://flespi.com/protocols/mqtt) messages to flespi channel. And flespi will stream processed information to MS Azure and/or AWS in their specific protocols.

Comment: Hello shal,

Connection established

Comment: hello shal,
thanks for replying!!
the connection is established with Azure using the host, port, username and, password.
but still, I get publish error.
is there any solution to solve out this problem?
thanks!!

Comment: Look into device policy, may be that will help.